# Only-numerics in Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a snippet that only allows numbers to be typed into an input:

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(event) { 
    var charCode = event.which;
    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 
    return /[0-9]/.test(keyChar); 
});
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wgsPr/

How can I adjust this to prevent typing in numbers greater than 500?

For example, if a user types `50`, then types a `1` after, it won't display the 1. However if the user types a `0` after, it will display `500`. And the same goes for if a user tries to type `968` it will not show the `8`, it will only show `96`.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Do not try to prevent key events (that just makes your form unusable, and leads to bad UX)! Instead, validate the input's whole *value*

Comment: My code is more complex, in that it calculates the user input immediately on keypress; it results in undefined when the value exceeds 500, which is bad UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line would be

```
return /\d/.test(keyChar) && parseInt(this.value+keyChar, 10) <= 500;
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wgsPr/2/))

However, I still suggest not to hook on and preventDefault of `keypress` events - go for `keyup` and `change` events and show error messages if the input's value is invalid. Or use a HTML5 `<input type="number" />` with min and max attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not use such methods. This works far better:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="500" />
```

However, if you insist, take your existing code and replace the `return` line with:

```
return /\d/.test(keyChar) && this.value <= 500;
```

Comment: No. Try to type 999 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wgsPr/1/) - it simply works (and if you remove the `maxlength`, you even can enter `5000`)

Comment: But it won't let you submit such an out-of-bounds value. That's all that matters.

Comment: What do you mean by "not submit"? I don't see an `submit` handler :-)

Comment: That's because the browser handles it for you. That's what the HTML5 form features are all about. The server should do the checking, since client-side content can never be trusted, but for the front-end using native systems where available is always a good idea. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgsPr/3/) with anything but old versions of IE.

Comment: Uh, I was only referring to the non-working keypress handler. HTML5 (shimmed or with native browser UX) is a good idea of course :-)

Comment: I realised that just after I typed my last comment XD Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).val() > 500) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).val().length - 1));
    return false;
}
```

I went ahead and attempted to solve this myself, which works. Basically, it checks the value and remove the last character in the case that it makes the entire input value larger than `500`. Please let me know if anything should be modified.

Comment: I'm not sure that's such a good idea. After all, if I type `501`, the result is `50` in the box... If you're going to go along this path, try `if( this.value > 500) this.value = 500;`.